# Schema as a parameter in a function

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to have a schema as a parameter in a function such as

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_data_for_weekly_front_end_collections_summary(@schema VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @schema.db1
)
```

**The error:**

[image]

Comment: No, you can't do this. Such syntax would require dynamic SQL, which you *cannot* use in a function. The error is because you start your query with a subquery, not a `SELECT`. Those paratheses should *not* be there.

Comment: And a moot point anyway but the correct datatype for schema would be `SYSNAME` not `VARCHAR` (which is equivalent to `VARCHAR(1)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSQL doesn't support parametrizing object names in queries, and user-defined functions don't support dynamic SQL.  But  you can do something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_data_for_weekly_front_end_collections_summary(@schema NVARCHAR(200))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(

    select *
    from a.db1
    where @schema = 'a'
    union all
    select * 
    from b.db1
    where @schema = 'b'
)
```

Comment: Then if I have to union 2 of the same queries but from different schemas, then I just have to copy-paste the same query but change the schema name?

That makes debugging so much more tedious.

Comment: *"TSQL doesn't support parametrizing object names"* There is *one* exception to this, Stored Procedures. `DECLARE @ProcName sysname = N'sys.sp_executesql'; EXEC @ProcName N'SELECT 123 AS I';` is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: @NoName If that type of debugging is tedious for you, then you shouldn't be using a function, use a stored procedure where you can use dynamic SQL to have _one copy_ of the query that you then slip in the schema name dynamically, e.g. `SET @command = N'SELECT ... FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + N'.table ...`.